# ¿Cómo abro un enlace en una nueva pestaña y despues cambio el header con php javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

Tengo el siguiente php con el que, primero evaluo si existe algun checkbox marcado o todos estan vacios.

*Si ningun checkbox esta marcado, refresca la misma pagina
*Si alguno esta marcado, exporta un archivo y se descarga con el navegador

Quisiera abrir otra pagina en una nueva pestaña y luego exportar el archivo, pero solo he conseguido, o una u otra.

Les dejo el codigo que descarga la exportacion:

```
<?php
  ob_start();
?>
<?php 
if($_POST['chkbox'] =="" ) {
    //exit();
    header("location:consulta.php");
}
echo '<script>window.open("miarchivo.lbx","_blank")</script>';
// tested with success
$db_name     = "db";
$db_password = "pass";
$db_link     = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", $db_password);
mysql_select_db($db_name, $db_link);
mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8");

$table = "articulos";

function assoc_query_2D($sql, $id_name = false){
  $result = mysql_query($sql);
  $arr = array();
  $row = array();
  if($result){
    if($id_name == false){
      while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        $arr[] = $row;
    }else{
      while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $id = $row['id'];
        $arr[$id] = $row;
      }
    }
  }else
      return 0;

  return $arr;
}
//Cast all ids to integer
$ids = $_POST['chkbox'];
array_walk($ids, function(&$value, $key) {
    $value = (int)$value;
});

$ids = implode(', ', $ids);
function query_whole_table($table, $value = '*'){
    $sql = "SELECT $value FROM $table WHERE id IN ($ids)";
  return assoc_query_2D($sql);
}

$export_str = '"Id","Nombre","Descripcion","Proveedor","Cantidad","Numero de serie","Categoria","id_pedido","id_usuario","Empresa","Ubicacion","Codigo de barras"'."\n";
$result = query_whole_table($table);

foreach($result as $record){
  $export_str .= '"'.implode('","',$record) .'"'."\n";
}
// output the file 
// we can set a header to send it directly to the browser
file_put_contents($table.".csv", $export_str);
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');   
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\""."articulos.csv"."\"");  
echo $export_str; exit;
header("location:miarchivo.lbx");
?>
<?php
  ob_end_flush();
?>
```

De acuerdo, quise simplificar mi problema y por eso solo pregunte lo ultimo que necesitaba o lo que yo crei que me estaba fallando, pero intentare exponer mi problema lo más claro posible:

Tengo un php de consulta de artículos con: una barra de navegación, búsqueda y filtrado por categorías, proveedores, etc,y su tabla de consultas

Esa tabla tiene una columna de checkboxes, las cuales tienen como propiedad value, los ids de los artículos, y un botón de descarga, para bajar la base de datos y una plantilla para un software de escritorio.

El problema surge de querer descargar la base de datos, con artículos específicos solamente, y por eso se me ocurrió utilizar checkboxes, donde el usuario pudiera descargar la base de datos con los artículos que requiriera solamente.

No he trabajado mucho con estos escenarios, pero vi un video de como enviar multiples valores de checkbox utilizando una lista (por ello, inclui esto en la funcion: $ids = implode(', ', $ids);) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jx4qVolKkJQ

El motivo de este post fue que no podia realizar ninguna accion, si alguno de los 2 archivos que necesito se descarga, y por eso pense en abrirlo en una nueva pestaña y continuar con la exportacion, por ejemplo.

En realidad el problema general es completamente distinto al post, pero esa fue la solución que se me ocurrio y tal vez si me estoy complicando más...

Comment: @Mariano hice esto <?php
  ob_start();
?>
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0,url=consulta.php"></head>
<body >
  <?php 
if($_POST['chkbox'] =="" ) {
    //exit();
  header("location:consulta.php");
}
echo '<script>window.open("miarchivo.lbx")</script>';
echo '<script>window.open("descargar2.php")</script>';

?>
</body></html>
<?php
  ob_end_flush();
?>   PERO EN EL SEGUNDO PHP YA NO ME DETECTA LOS CHECKBOXES MARCADOS

Comment: Quizá esto te pueda servir:
http://www.forosdelweb.com/f18/descargar-fichero-redireccionar-679244/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El principal problema que veo es que no se puede modificar el header con PHP una vez que se ha devuelto algún caracter, así que te recomiendo que modifiques el header mediante Javascript después de abrir la nueva ventana:

```
echo '
<script>
window.open("miarchivo.lbx","_blank");
location.href= "consulta.php";
</script>';
```